# How to access ViewController component from PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 simple view as following

[image]

first one is PageView second one is simple viewController with an image view on top

viewController code as follows

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "dog0")
    }
}
```

When i run this view controller as initial view controller. it works fine. it shows the image properly

but when i do the same from a page view controller with following code

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    let imageNames = ["dog0","dog1","dog2"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        let eachView = ViewController()
        eachView.imageName = imageNames.first
        let viewControllers = [eachView]
        setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }


}
```

and

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageName : String? {
        didSet {
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

I get following error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on line

```
imgView.image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
```

What is the problem & how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let eachView = ViewController()
```

This creates a ViewController instance "out of thin air", without any associated main `view`. Thus, when the view loads, it is empty. Thus, there is no image view in the view, and `imgView` is `nil`. Thus, when you refer to `imgView` as if it were not `nil` (trying to set its `image`), you crash.

The correct procedure is to instantiate the ViewController that you have designed *in the storyboard*. *That* ViewController instance has an image view in its `view`, because you designed it (you put it there), and it has an `imgView` outlet, as you already know, again because you designed it (you put it there).

To obtain *that* ViewController instance, get a reference to the storyboard (probably as `self.storyboard`) and call [`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller). Of course you will have to have assigned an identifier to this ViewController instance in the storyboard.

Then you need to rewrite ViewController like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageName : String? {
        didSet {
            imgView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView? // note the question mark

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        imgView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName!) // note the repeat
    }
}
```

The reason is that you now have a timing problem: you are setting `imageName` before the view loads, so `imgView` *still* hasn't hooked up to its outlet. By moving the key line into `viewDidLoad`, you make sure that we do this *after* we actually have a view and an outlet.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: @LynAs I think I've now provided a sufficient explanation! Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I am instantiating the view controller this way `let eachView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageScroller") as! ViewController` still getting the same error. can you tell me why??

Comment: I have also tried `let eachView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageScroller") as! ViewController`

Comment: ok I end up using UserDefaults to pass the image name. This does not look like the right way but it works for me for now

Comment: No, I see what the new problem is. Hang on, I'll add more about that.

Comment: No worries. I hope you understand everything we did.